# Can't restart UWP application via CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to restart the application, but I get `NotInForeground` error every time.

I tried to close every other application and loop the restart attempt to make sure it is in foreground like this

```
var loopRestart = true;
            while (loopRestart)
            {
                var failureReason = await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("-fastInit -level 1");
                loopRestart = failureReason == AppRestartFailureReason.NotInForeground;
            }
```

With or without parameters (from one of the examples found on the internet) it just won't let me do it. When I do `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView()` is says that the window is `ActivatedInForeground` [quickwatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4cnK.png). At this point I'm lost. Version is 2004

Comment: Could you please tell me how you test this? Is it a blank UWP application? Is there other devices to test?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT another device will arrive in a few days, but the app is not blank, no

Comment: The code works as expected on my side. I'm testing in a blank UWP project. Could you please try in a new project?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT tried a blank project. Everything's fine as well

Comment: So it works in another app. It seems that issue is related to your original app. Do you have any special functions in your app that will make your app no responding?